# silverlight authentication

Tags: silverlight, authentication

Good day!
I have an silverlight site (silverlight navigation application) and I want clients to log in on my site. I want to give them different rights of viewing pages.
A WCF service gives me true or false when I enter a login and a password. Then, if it returns true, I want to remember the logged user. 
How can I do it? Using cookies or global variable or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at WCF RIA Service in a combination with the ASP.NET Membership Provider.
There is also a Template for an AuthenticationService...
Examples here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2010/03/26/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-authentication-and-personalization.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/05/03/accessing-the-asp-net-authentication-profile-and-role-service-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although [www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL3WindowsIdentityName.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL3WindowsIdentityName.aspx) is based upon Windows Authentication, could you not adapt the first part of it for your needs?